# Error: intrinsic gas too low while deploying contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am trying to setup a contract in my private ethereum network. For that, I picked up a sample contract code from the internet:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract getSchwifty {
  string internal constant seeWhatYouGot = "I want to see what you got!";
  string internal contestResult;

  // Contract constructor that takes a string param
  function getSchwifty(string _contestResult) public {
    contestResult = _contestResult;
  }

  function showMeWhatYouGot() external pure returns (string) {
    return seeWhatYouGot;  
  }

  function enterContest(string _contestEntry) external view returns (string) {
    // completely disregard the _contestEntry ;)
    return contestResult;
  }
}
```

I compiled the abi and bytecode for this and am using it to deploy the contract.

```
var getSchwifty = eth.contract(<ABI generated from solc --abicommand>)
var bytecode = '0x<bytecode generated from solc --bin command>'
```

and then did

```
var deploy = {from:eth.coinbase, data:bytecode, gas: 4000}
var getSchwiftyPartialInstance = getSchwifty.new("DISQUALIFIED!", deploy)
```

basically here I am trying to create a new instance of the contract I wrote above I guess. However, the last step fails with the error:

```
> var getSchwiftyPartialInstance = getSchwifty.new("TEST", deploy)
Error: intrinsic gas too low
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at web3.js:3021:24
    at <anonymous>:1:34
```

I tried: `eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit`. this gives 5003. I have set gasLimit to the same value in genesis.json as well.

I get the above error for different values of gas in `var deploy = {from:eth.coinbase, data:bytecode, gas: 4000}`. If I increase the value to something higher than the limit obtained from: `eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit`, I get an error: exceeds gas limit.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong and what steps I could take. I did ensure that the peer is talking other peers.

Comment: Intrinsic gas is `21000`, every transaction must pay at least that much. You will likely need much more for deploying a contract.

Comment: where does eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit get its value from? EVen with gas Limit much higher, this command always gives me around 5003.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting 5003, but that command will usually give the maximum possible gas that block could have consumed. It seems odd that it is under the intrinsic gas, though

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RaghavSood. Not sure if it matters, this is a private  ethereum network(geth).

Comment: And sometimes, I get an error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value if I decrease the value of gas in: var deploy = {from:eth.coinbase, data:bytecode, gas: 4000}

Comment: @techieChamp When you created the network in your genesis file you didn't specify a gas amount or it was too low. In your case probably is better to edit the genesis file and recreate your private network.

Comment: @Ismael, I did set the gasLimit in genesis to a higher value. It still picks up around 5000 though.

Comment: @techieChamp If you want to increase your gas limit you have two options: 1) modify geneses and recreate your private network discarding old blocks; 2) relaunch your geth with `--targetgaslimit <new_limit>` to increase gas limit.